# Lock screen image change

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, lockscreen

Here is my code:

```
Uri u = new Uri(@"C:\roomieUser\w3.tif");
Windows.System.UserProfile.LockScreen.RequestSetImageFeedAsync(u);
```

I am trying to change the lock screen in a Windows forms application. I have managed to use WinRT libraries in Windows forms application and there are two methods to change picture one is written above and other is as below

```
LockScreen.SetImageFileAsync(); //But it requires IStorageFile passed in method
```

I have pictures stored in "resources" folder, is there any method to convert/use these pictures as `IStorageFile`?

File path is correct but when I tries to run it shows an error message that

> Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)

Answer (score 0):

[`LockScreen.RequestSetImageFeedAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.lockscreen.requestsetimagefeedasync) is supposed to be called with a Uri pointing to an RSS feed, not an image. This method is deprecated in Windows 10.

You can use [`StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.getfilefromapplicationuriasync) to get files from the application's resources folder.